# Combining three EXISTS

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

How do we get the intersection of the following three sets?

```
//A
SELECT 
{} ON 0,
EXISTS(
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
    , {[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[1]}
    , "Internet Sales")
 ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]

//B
SELECT 
{} ON 0,
EXISTS(
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
    , {[Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory].&[2]}
    , "Internet Sales")
 ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]

//C
SELECT 
{} ON 0,
EXISTS(
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
    , {[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[477]}
    , "Internet Sales")
 ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Can the three members from the Product dimension get included one `EXISTS` function?

I could nest the use nested INTERSECTION around three EXISTS like the following but it seems very messy!...

```
SELECT 
{} ON 0,
INTERSECT(
    EXISTS(
        [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
        , {[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[477]}
        , "Internet Sales"),
    INTERSECT(
            EXISTS(
                [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
                , {[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[1]}
                , "Internet Sales"),
            EXISTS(
                [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
                , {[Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory].&[2]}
                , "Internet Sales")
            )
    )
 ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,Exists
  (
    Exists
    (
      Exists
      (
        [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
       ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory].&[2]}
       ,"Internet Sales"
      )
     ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[1]}
     ,"Internet Sales"
    )
   ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[477]}
   ,"Internet Sales"
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Philip,